# Microsoft Visual Studio 14 - failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, pycharm, build-tools

I have installed the latest version of [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) on **Windows 10** to develop on my python project. But i am not able to install any packages from the python pypi libary.

When i try to install a package (any package, not just the mysql) it crashed with the folowing error:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe'
failed with exit status 2
```

I reinstalled the Build Tools for Visual Studio 17 (Build tools 14) and i also installed any given sdk or feature from the visual Studio. But still the same problem.

Running on Python 3.6 and Python 3.7 with both similar problems. When I try to install the package via the commandline.

```
py -3.6 -m pip install mysql
```

And i got the folowing error message:

```
_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge”ffnet werden: "mysql.h": No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\****~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jjudeiox\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-opzlo6th\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\****~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jjudeiox\mysqlclient\
```